# Remove rel=shortlink from HTTP header

Tags: headers, http

HTTP header of posts on my site looks like this:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:public, max-age=0,public,public
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:5369
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Fri, 08 Dec 2017 07:27:40 GMT
expires:Fri, 08 Dec 2017 07:19:33 GMT
link:<https://example.com/?p=5697>; rel=shortlink
server:Apache
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

How to remove this line from HTTP header responce:

```
link:<https://example.com/?p=5697>; rel=shortlink
```

*Please, do not confuse this with `<head> </head>` section of HTML, I removed it from there already, I would like to remove it from HTTP header response too.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<?php
add_filter('after_setup_theme', 'remove_redundant_shortlink');

function remove_redundant_shortlink() {
    // remove HTML meta tag
    // <link rel='shortlink' href='http://example.com/?p=25' />
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10);

    // remove HTTP header
    // Link: <https://example.com/?p=25>; rel=shortlink
    remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_shortlink_header', 11);
}
```

Tested in WordPress 4.4 and up to 4.9.1

Comment: It is not working for me, I have first line of code in my functions.php, and it removes shortlink from <head> section, but not from http header. I tried second function too, but nothing I still have shortlink in http header. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AdvancedSEO, have a look at fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

This still works in wordpress 5.8.3 if you put it in your themes functions.php - just remember that this file might alter at upgrade.

Solution is [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288089/remove-rel-shortlink-from-http-header)

Comment: You could put it in a child theme or a plugin then - it doesn't have to go in the theme's functions.php.